# Events being bound twice or more jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to generate html on the fly with javascript. I'm binding on the click of buttons on my page. There are multiple buttons on my page which are causing my elements to be bound multiple times which produces the desired results to appear in the amount of times the button has been clicked.

My question is there something that can check if a element is already bound in jquery? If so, how do I incorporate that with the .live() function in jquery.

Here is my code:

```
$(document).ready(

    function () {
        $(':button').live("click", ".textbox, :button", function () {
            alert("binding");
            $(".textbox").click(function () {
                defaultVal = this.defaultValue;
                if (this.defaultValue) {
                    this.value = "";
                }
            });
            $(".textbox").blur(function () {
                if (this.value == "") {
                    this.value = defaultVal;
                }
            });
            $('[name="numsets"]').blur(function () {
                if (!parseInt(this.value)) {
                    $(this).val("you need to enter a number");
                }
            });
            $('[name="weightrepbutton"]').click(function () {
                var $numsets = $(this).parent().children('[name="numsets"]');
                if ($numsets.val() != "you need to enter a number" && $numsets.val() != "Number of Sets") {
                    var numbersets = parseInt($numsets.val())
                    repandweight.call(this, numbersets)
                    $(this).hide();
                    $numsets.hide();
                }
            })
        });
    });
```

The problem is line 4, every time a button is clicked, all functions that were previous bound seem to be bound to the same function twice, which is a problem.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: which version of jQuery you are using ?

Comment: jQuery v1.7.2 is what i'm using

Comment: then you should use on instead of live.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are doing it twice ! One inside another. Take out the outer binding  and it should work

```
$(document).ready(function () {

      $(document).on("click",".textbox",function () {
          defaultVal = this.defaultValue;
          if (this.defaultValue) {
               this.value = "";
          }
      });

      $(document).on("blur",".textbox",function () {
          var item=$(this);
          if (item.val() == "") {
               item.val(defaultVal);
          }
      });

      $(document).on("blur","input[name='numsets']",function () {
          var item=$(this);
          if (!parseInt(item.val())) {
                item.val("you need to enter a number");
          }
      });

      $(document).on("click","input[name='weightrepbutton']",function () {
                var $numsets = $(this).parent().children('[name="numsets"]');
                if ($numsets.val() != "you need to enter a number" && $numsets.val() != "Number of Sets") {
                    var numbersets = parseInt($numsets.val())
                    repandweight.call(this, numbersets)
                    $(this).hide();
                    $numsets.hide();
                }
      })            
    });
```

if you are using jQuery 1.7+ version, consider switching to jQuery [on](http://api.jquery.com/on/) instead of `live`.

EDIT: Updated `live` to `on` as OP mentioned it in the comment.

Comment: this causes nothing to be bound on my site. I have new elements that are being added that need to be bound. These are replacing the old, previously bound elements.

Comment: check whether you have any other script errrors. I am going to update my answer to use on as you mentioned you use a version higher thatn 1.7

Comment: Everything runs just fine in the firebug console, except for the multiple bindings.

Comment: i updated with on. Try that and see. Make sure you have the correct selectors.